# Okta SAML 2.0 dynamic configuration in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

Is there a way to add a new IDP at runtime from database while using Spring Security Extension for SAML 2.0.

Actually we have enterprise application, so each enterprise have separate authentication OKTA SAML 2.0 application for authentication.

How to add new Identity Provider into Java Web application by taking required attributes from User at runtime without restarting the server or application.

I referred this demo : https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/16/spring-boot-saml
but this demo has static configuration from application.properties that I don't want.